# .append() for two lists in python. Check thinking

Tags: python

I have question to explain me what is the correct thinking about this case.

I have two lists,

```py
a = [1]
b = [a]
a.append(2)
```

edit: The result of code:

```py
>>> a 
[1, 2]
>>> b 
[[1, 2]]
```

I think about this cases as a list `b` has references for list `a`. Is that correct thinking?

Comment: did you try it? what happened? what were you expecting? here is a visualization: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20%5Ba%5D%0Aa.append%282%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: I tried your code, `b = [[1, 2]]`

Comment: Result of this code: ```>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> b
[[1, 2]]```

Comment: So, that is reference

Comment: @JuanC no, absolutely *not*. The semantics here are exactly the same for all objects, regardless of types.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't accurate in my language, But if you do `x=2` , `y=x` , `x=x+2`, `y` won't get automatically updated. When you perform similar operations with lists,like in this post, the list will get automatically updated. That's what I meant

Comment: @JuanC no, *absolutely not*. Consider, `x = [2]; y = x; x = x + [2]; print(x, y)`

Comment: Many thanks for discussion!

Comment: @JuanC the key issue is that assignment always has the exact same semantics in python. However, immutable types *lack mutator methods*.

Comment: You're right, my bad. What _is_ actually puzzling for newcomers is the behaviour of list-specific methods, because they automatically change the list without assignation and change every list that references said list. Every now and then I forget why `x = x.append(2)` isn't working, because I equate it in my head to `x = x+[2]`

Comment: @JuanC I understand what you are getting at, I just push back because there is a lot of confusion on this topic that persists among beginners, and Python currently is inundated with begginers as it has become a popular teaching language. No doubt *you* understand it, but I think the problem is that there are many students not truly understanding what's going on and getting by on half-truths about how assignment is "different depending on the type", or mutable and immutable types have different semantics. I usually just refer people to this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I always love to stand corrected if the correction is right, like this case. I don't come from a software engineering background, so I'm sometimes inaccurate with my language and sometimes I don't really understand what's happening behind the scenes, but _I want to_. In short, this was enlightening and I'll read your reference, thank you !

Comment: Just now I'm really understanding the difference between mutable and immutable objects and how it relates to this discussion, thanks for the resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, b will be a list that contains list a. You can confirm this by comparing the two.

```py
a = [1]
b = [a]
a.append(2)

print(b[0] == a)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, Python list stores references. This subject can get confusing,
>   due to the way numbers are treated in Python. Some people mistakenly
>   think that it depends on the stored data-type, which is incorrect.
>   Lists always contain references, even for numeric types

The answer would [[1, 2]]